# Conditional string insertion

Tags: python, regex

Can we write a Python program to turn

```
2.4 Threads /35,Black,notBold,notItalic,closed,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
      2.4.1 Multithreading/35,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
          2.4.4.1 Hierarchical Design 28/39,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
```

into

```
2.4 Threads 24/35,Black,notBold,notItalic,closed,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
      2.4.1 Multithreading 24/35,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
          2.4.4.1 Hierarchical Design 28/39,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
```

The gist is:

1. Each line has a `/`, followed by a number and a comma.
2. If there is no number in front of `/`, then add the number minus 11 in front of `/`.
3. If there is already a number in front of `/`, then just leave the line alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the RegEx, `(\s*\d*)/(\d+)` to capture both the numbers around `/` and then you can replace the first number based on your conditions with a custom function, like this

```
def replacer(matchobj):
    if matchobj.group(1).lstrip() == "":
        return " {}/{}".format(int(matchobj.group(2)) - 11, matchobj.group(2))
    else:
        return "/".join(matchobj.groups())

print(re.sub(r"(\s*\d*)/(\d+)", replacer, data))
```

**Output**

```
2.4 Threads 24/35,Black,notBold,notItalic,closed,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
      2.4.1 Multithreading 24/35,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
          2.4.4.1 Hierarchical Design 28/39,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
```

The RegEx `(\s*\d*)/(\d+)` means that, match zero or more spaces followed by zero or more digits followed by `/` character and then one or more digits.